# php code to display Product description from other website

Tags: php, smarty

I need to integrate my prestashop website my Ice-cat.

Below mentioned is the format to pull data.

General format: 
http://prf.icecat.biz/index.cgi?prod_id=;vendor=;shopname=

Example: 
http://prf.icecat.biz/index.cgi?prod_id=LX.TEQ06.029;vendor=acer;shopname=openIcecat-url

How do i integrate this in prestashop.

Any code idea would help very much.

How do i build this url from database table ID , I have more than 100 products , Product table conatins the product id and vendor name.I need to create a script when runs it updates all products description field with the respective data fetched from URL

Answer (score 0):

No idea about prestashop.

But if you want to extract the variables from the url try -

```
<?php
$pattern = '/[;]/';

$string = "http://prf.icecat.biz/index.cgi?prod_id=LX.TEQ06.029;vendor=acer;shopname=openIcecat-url";

print_r( preg_split( $pattern, $string ), 1 );
?>
```

That will split the string up by ';' where you can then explode() by the '=' and get the data.

Comment: How do i build this url from  database table ID , I have more than 100 products , Product table conatins the product id and vendor name.I need to create a script when runs it updates all products description field with the respective data fetched from URL